# How to find the process id of a process running on a port number in java

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I am new to java and window as well I want to kill the process which is running on a specific port. let's say 9090.

what I tried

```
try{
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = rt.exec("netstat -ano | findstr 9090");

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(
                                     new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    String s = null;

    if ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        int index=s.lastIndexOf(" ");
        String sc=s.substring(index, s.length());

        rt.exec("Taskkill /PID" +sc+" /T /F");

    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server Stopped");
}catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something Went wrong with server");
}
```

Comment: Please provide what output/error you got when you executed above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is What you want to do . I hope it will help you.

```
try{
               Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
               Process proc = rt.exec("cmd /c netstat -ano | findstr 9090");

               BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
               InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
               String s = null;
               if ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
               int index=s.lastIndexOf(" ");
               String sc=s.substring(index, s.length());

               rt.exec("cmd /c Taskkill /PID" +sc+" /T /F");

       }
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server Stopped");
         }catch(Exception e){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something Went wrong with server");
           }
```

Comment: can you please tell if same thing has to be implemented for mac?i want ti kill port on mac

Comment: @VikramSaini This solution uses Windows commands